# Laravel .env - can I save some variables in database?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, mailgun

I want put my MAILGUN_SECREY and others keys in database,
I have a model for variables and I access it like this:

```
\App\Variable::getByClave('MAILGUN_SECRET')->pluck('valor')->first();
```

what would be the correct way to update the .env or overwrite it from DDBB?
Thx :)

Comment: Please add a relevant code snippet of what you have tried.

Comment: If you have in DB why do you need to update in ``env``? :/

Comment: Considering configuration variables for your Database connection are stored in `.env`, don't you think it's a little odd to have them stored in your database instead? How do you connect to your Database to pull `.env` variables? Chicken/egg scenario there. But I digress; you can store configuration in a database if you'd like, just don't try to write to your `.env` file from that. The "correct" way to update/overwrite `.env` would be not to. It's a bad idea from a security standpoint, and Laravel even suggests not pulling directly from `.env` in production, rather use the `config()` helper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can edit the config on the fly in your `AppServiceProvider.php` method `register`

```
  class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
        /**
         * Register any application services.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function register()
        {
            //fetch your credentials from the db..
            //then set it like this
            config(['services.mailgun.secret'=>1234]); 
        }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's just what I was looking for.